# Get URL with variables

Tags: url, variables, coldfusion

How would I go about obtaining the URL of the requested page together with all variables? I know how to get the URL without variables.

eg. /forums/index.cfm?id=10&cat=5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dump out the cgi variables and you'll find what you are looking for and more.

```
<cfdump var="#cgi#">
```

Comment: Ha! So much useful variables I had no idea about. Thanks :D.

Answer (score 0):

Sam is correct about using:

```
<cfdump var="#cgi#">
```

However, what you may be interested in are the values from the CGI scope.  For example, the CGI.HTTP_REFERER and CGI.HTTP_USER_AGENT.  Please note the HTTP_REFERER will only be populated when the CGI.REQUEST_METHOD is POST and not on a GET request.